# AJAX request is not sent before previous request is not finished

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, apache, internet-explorer

I'm seeing strange behaviour with AJAX request being stuck before the previous request (not AJAX) is finished.

I have a web page where video using HTML5  is playing and during that I want to make an AJAX request to the server.

Below is some details of my case.
Here is how it looks when request is stuck. First one is the video, second one is the AJAX which I want to send and it doesn't go anywhere before 1st is completed.
[image]

As soon as 1st is completed the 2nd one is done immediately.
[image]

Ajax request is sent using just normal jQuery's $.ajax() call.

Here is the request and response information for the video request that blocks AJAX request.

```
Request GET /portal/portlet/index/id/671/call/proxyVideo?entityId=1 HTTP/1.1
Accept  */*
If-Unmodified-Since Fri, 24 Apr 2015 08:18:29 GMT
If-Match    "f91b54d-514740a87ff40"
Range   bytes=360448-261207372
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Referer http://mm.mac/content
GetContentFeatures.DLNA.ORG 1
Pragma  getIfoFileURI.dlna.org
Accept-Language en-US
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Host    mm.mac
Connection  Keep-Alive
Cache-Control   no-cache
Cookie  PHPSESSID=41821op72k2s24mfrsbn5gad64


Response    HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Date    Tue, 01 Dec 2015 13:39:31 GMT
Server  Apache/2.4.16 (Unix) PHP/5.6.13
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.6.13
Expires Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control   no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma  no-cache
Last-Modified   Fri, 24 Apr 2015 08:18:29 GMT
ETag    "f91b54d-514740a87ff40"
Accept-Ranges   bytes
Content-Length  260846925
Access-Control-Allow-Methods    GET
Content-Range   bytes 360448-261207372/261207373
Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=100
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Type    video/mp4
```

My question is why the AJAX request is blocked and how can I make it work?

PS: Console doesn't report any errors or warnings.

Comment: Can you try to check what is the `readyState` for your Ajax call ..

Comment: The `readyState` is `1` as soon as it is created. Do I need to check that in some time after it was created but before 'onsuccess'? I'm checking the Apache log at the same time and I do not see the request there before the request is completed.

Answer (score 0):

Make async:true in your ajax parameter

Comment: Explain your anwser a little, why OP should do this ?

Comment: just because of ajax is by default async true, it means you can run other service at same time while one ajax processing. if you set async:false other services will not be run before current ajax will not be completed

Comment: Not in comment, in your answer :) When you give an answer, try to explain why it is supposed to solve the problem ! That way beginner or other people that have the same problem can use id and understand